# Method call function in a table row clone editable

Tags: javascript, clone, jeditable

I have cloned the rows in my [table editable](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/WKaR9/6/).

The rows have 2 column editable, 1 with editable textarea and the other one with an input numer.

There is a function which sum the numbers in the two input numbers and give the total. You can try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/WKaR9/6/), there is `onblur : "submit"`

I have cloned both Rows, they are editable but the function to calculate the Total does not work in the rows cloned.

How can i make my function working in the cloned rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are cloning rows with `id="sum"`, and you should not have duplicated `id`s in your page.

when i have to clone elements i generate dynamic `id`s so they don't get duplicated.

like this:

```
var lastid = $('[id^="clonedInput"]').length + 1;
$(".clonedInput").last().clone().attr('id', 'clonedInput' + lastid).appendTo("body")
```

you can test a full working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/MjMh5/

*also, your jsfiddle is a total mess. please keep only the relevant code.*

### EDIT

ok, so you have other problems as well.
for instance, your function tally does not sum the cloned rows.
this function (not mention your whole code) could be a lot simpler.

```
function tally() {
    var total = 0;
    $('p.editable_number').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
        $('#total').html(total);
    })
}
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/MA78A/

Comment: Yes ok, the ID="sum" does not get duplicated, but my case is a bit different, i ahve tried to apply the same concept in my scripr                              var lastid = $('[id^="sum"]').length + 1;
                $(".editable_number").last().clone().attr('id', 'sum' + lastid).appendTo("body")

Comment: Oh thanks i was trying to make again everything with the example you linked but now i am going to study the whole code you edited. Yes basically the problem was that in my cloned rows the function tally was not working. Very appreciate RASG